# This is really embarrassing, but oftentimes I skip davening when I am really stressed out or tired. How can I fix this?

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, maariv, mincha-afternoon-prayer

I’m really depressed right now. I just want to be a good Jew and everything, but things seem to block me. I’m often really stressed out and tired, and that leads to me davening with a ton of stuttering and saying words incorrectly. Then I just don’t daven, but I feel extremely depressed and guilty for it.
How can I fix this? I just want to be a good Jew. But it seems like nobody can relate to me, so how can I even get out of this?

Comment: Hi Raphael. Firstly, it may not seem like people can relate to you about this, but there are a lot of people who can! It may seem like this is the kind of thing you can't bring to your Rabbi (and of course it depends on the Rabbi), but there are many Rabbis who would understand this and be able to give advice. So don't be put off when we tell you that this is not a question for Mi Yodeya (which it unfortunately isn't, although if you can make it more general then it could be an excellent question) - keep seeking the answers and you will B'EH find them quickly. Hatzlacha

Comment: But it really is just so embarrassing though. I feel so off the derech for it. But if i do daven, i end up saying Hashem’s name multiple times, which is a bad aveirah too! I just feel so trapped and it is really making me fall apart. And it seems like there is a bit of a cultural stigma to davening. Like even if the davening isn’t properly done, it’s still consider way, way better than not davenign at all, even if a person just didn’t actually daven even though it looked like it.

Comment: But yes, I do realize that this is a personal question that isn’t ideal for this website. But I’m scared that if I tell someone in real life they’ll think I’m off the derech.

Comment: @RaphaelChilungu Only an idiot would think you're off the derech for seeking help for how to daven better.